# Difference between Node->next!=NULL and Node!=NULL in C

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

This function doesn't work if I make a modification in `while` condition and change `temp != NULL` to `temp->next = NULL`. Why is that?

```
void Print() {
     printf("\n");
     printf("The Library data is as follows: \n");
     struct Node *temp = head; // where head is a global variable
     printf("\n");
     while (temp != NULL) {
         printf("%25s", temp->name);
         printf("%25s", temp->author);
         temp = temp->next;
         printf("\n");
     }
}
```

Plus if I modify the `while` loop condition under `else` block, from `temp1->next = NULL` to `temp1 != NULL`, it doesn't work. Why is that?

```
void Insert(char q[50], char r[50]) {
    struct Node *temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->next = NULL; // Since we are adding a node to the end, we are linking it to NULL.
    strcpy(temp->name, q); // copying the contents of "q" to "temp->name"
    strcpy(temp->author, r); // same
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = temp;
    } else {
        struct Node *temp1 = head;
        while (temp1->next != NULL)
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        temp1->next = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `temp` might be `NULL`. You must establish that before you dereference it. If it is, you have reached the end of the linked list. BTW you usually add an item to the *head* of a linked list, not to the tail.

Comment: Because the code as written, expresses the correct algorithms for iterating/extending linked lists and your changes express an incorrect algorithm. I recommend you spend some time with a whiteboard: [a]->[b]->[c]->null. Iterate to the end of the list such that you have {c,null}, then extend it with {d,null} and think about it. Another good exercise would be to work out the details of how to remove node b from the list.

Comment: If you change the boolean expression `temp- != NULL` to the assignment `temp->next = NULL` then the two things can happen: a) `temp` is initially `NULL` and you have a null pointer dereference; or b) `temp->next` is changed to `NULL` and as this is a false-y value, the loop is never executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Print` function, you want to enumerate all nodes in the list, and you want to handle an empty list (`head = NULL`) gracefully. Hence the loop iterates `while (temp == NULL)` and `temp` skips to the next node with `temp = temp->next;`.

In the `Insert` function, a new node is allocated and initialized. There is a special case for the empty list (`head == NULL`) where `head` just receives the pointer to the new node. Conversely, if the list is not empty, you want to find the **last** node of the list to append the new node by setting its `next` pointer to point to the new node. The loop iterates from the first to the last node, the test `temp1->next != NULL` succeeds if the node is not the last one. Hence `temp` points to the last node after the `while` loop and the new node can simply be appended with `temp1->next = temp;`.

Note the following remarks:

- the prototype `void Insert(char q[50], char r[50])` should be improved as `int Insert(const char *name, const char *author)` because:

  - the strings passed as arguments are not modified by the function
  - the argument names would be clearer
  - the array sizes specified are ignored by the compiler and seem inconsistent with the actual structure members.
  - the function can fail. It should at least return a success indicator.
- memory allocation should be tested for success and failure should be reported
- `strcpy` will cause undefined behavior if the arguments strings are too long.
- There is no need to cast the return value of `malloc` in C.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    char name[50];
    char author[50];
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *head = NULL;

void Print(void) {
     printf("\nThe Library data is as follows:\n\n");
     struct Node *temp = head; // where head is a global variable
     while (temp != NULL) {
         printf("%25s  %-25s\n", temp->name, temp->author);
         temp = temp->next;
     }
}

int Insert(const char *name, const char *author) {
    struct Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (temp == NULL)
        return -1;
    temp->next = NULL;
    snprintf(temp->name, sizeof(temp->name), "%s", name);
    snprintf(temp->author, sizeof(temp->author), "%s", author);

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = temp;
    } else {
        struct Node *temp1 = head;
        while (temp1->next != NULL)
            temp1 = temp1->next;
        temp1->next = temp;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    if (Insert("Flowers for Algernon", "Daniel Keyes")
    ||  Insert("Blade Runner", "Philip K. Dick")
    ||  Insert("2001, a Space Odyssey", "Arthur C. Clarke")) {
        printf("out of memory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    Print();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When change that to node->next in while loop its mean this loop loops while node->next is null so u miss last node of your linked array because this node's-next is null so loop is break in this time.And only write temp to your while u dont need temp != NULL this loop breaks when temp is null so only put

```
while(temp){
//your code
}
```

I hope this will be help you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the first case You are traversing through the entire linked list.End of linked list is denoted by `NULL` pointer as per your code so `while(temp!=NULL)` is used.This will work with `temp1->next!=NULL` if there are more than **2** nodes by skipping the last one.

In second case you add new node to the end of the last node.So you have to use `temp1->next!=NULL`. so that the last node's `next` pointer can point to the newly added node.If you use `temp!=NULL` in this case, Then temp becomes `NULL`. So the next statement `temp1->next=temp;` cannot work.

- If you make change in first case, it will only cause program to skip
  printing the last node in the linked list.
- If you make change in second case, this will cause your code to get 
  terminated `(runtime error)`.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple

1. In function `print()` when you use `while(temp->next!=null)` then it will not print last 
   node because when pointer temp is at last node `temp->next` is null and while condition 
   become false and it come out of while loop.
2. In function `insert()` if you change `while(temp1->next!=NULL)` to `while(temp1!=NULL)` then 
   when it come from while loop temp1 points to null means no memory is allocated .
   hence writing temp1->next in after while loop shows error as `you cannot excess next 
   part of temp because memory is not allocated`.

Hope this will help you!